# Is there a function to get random order of the data instead of seq order using xslt3.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Need to get the data in random order instead of sequential order of input.

Below is the xml source:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 1 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 1 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>9</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>9</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>10</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>10</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 1 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 2 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>5</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>5</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>7</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>7</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 2 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 2 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>7</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>7</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>10</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>10</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR 1 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR 1 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>8</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>8</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>6</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>6</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 2 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 2 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>6</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>6</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>7</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>7</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 3 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 3 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>Not enough information</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>8</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>8</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR2 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR2 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>6</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>6</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>6</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>6</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR3 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR3 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>Not enough information</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>10</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>10</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Manager</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>M response Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Manager</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>M response Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Manager</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>7</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>7</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Manager</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>6</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>6</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 3 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 3 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>8</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>8</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>7</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>7</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR4 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR4 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>8</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>8</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>4</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>4</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 4 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>PS 4 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>7</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>7</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Peer/Stakeholder</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>8</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>8</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Manager</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>M response Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Manager</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>M response Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Manager</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>6</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>6</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Manager</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>4</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>4</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR5 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR5 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>6</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>6</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>456</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>7</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>7</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR1 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR1 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>Not enough information</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>6</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>6</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>1</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR2 Q1&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>2</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>&lt;p>DR2 Q2&lt;/p></wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>0</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>3</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>9</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>9</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>123</wd:empid>
        <wd:category>Direct Report</wd:category>
        <wd:questionno>4</wd:questionno>
        <wd:response>10</wd:response>
        <wd:date>2023-12-01</wd:date>
        <wd:score>10</wd:score>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Here is the xslt 3.0 that I am using it but need the data in any random order (but not the same order):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Report_Data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Data"/>
        </Report_Data>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:function name="wd:formatPSQ">
        <xsl:param name="psqValue"/>
        <xsl:param name="lastElement"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('{\&quot;Response\&quot;:{\&quot;', $psqValue, '\&quot;}')"/>
        <xsl:if test="$lastElement = false()">
            <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>    
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:empid">
            <Report_Entry>
                <empid>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:empid"/>
                </empid>
                <DRPSQ1>
                    <xsl:if test="(current-group()[(wd:category ='Peer/Stakeholder' or wd:category = 'Direct Report') and wd:questionno='1']/wd:response)">
                        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each
                            select="current-group()[(wd:category ='Peer/Stakeholder' or wd:category = 'Direct Report') and wd:questionno='1']">
                            <xsl:text>{\"Response\":\"</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="parse-xml-fragment(wd:response)/p"/>
                         <xsl:text>\"}</xsl:text>                            
                            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </DRPSQ1>   
            </Report_Entry>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need the output similar to this for DRPSQ1 (not on the same order but randomized needed:
Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report_Data xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <Report_Entry>
        <empid>123</empid>
        <DRPSQ1>[{\"Response\":\"PS 2 Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"PS 3
            Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"PS 1 Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"DR2 Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"DR1 Q1\"}]</DRPSQ1>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <empid>456</empid>
        <DRPSQ1>[{\"Response\":\"PS 3
            Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"DR4 Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"PS 1 Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"DR5
            Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"PS 2
            Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"DR2 Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"DR3 Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"PS 4 Q1\"},{\"Response\":\"DR 1 Q1\"}]</DRPSQ1>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you populate the element `DRPSQ1` with e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()[(wd:category ='Peer/Stakeholder' or wd:category = 'Direct Report') and wd:questionno='1']">
```

I suppose you want to use

```
<xsl:for-each select="random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?permute(current-group()[(wd:category ='Peer/Stakeholder' or wd:category = 'Direct Report') and wd:questionno='1'])">
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you recommend to apply at for-each group level or each individual for-each field level.

Comment: @Buddi, call the `permute` function on the sequence you want to randomize, I understood it to be the sequence of values you put into the `DRPSQ1` element. The shown grouping result seems to be based on input document order.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<xsl:for-each-group 
  select="random-number-generator()?permute(wd:Report_Entry)" 
  group-by="wd:empid">
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you recommend to apply at for-each group level or each individual field level.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements well enough to answer that.